# How should be system configured for use breakpoints of xdebug for phpunit tests on netbeans (ubuntu)

Tags: php, netbeans, debug, phpunit, xdebug

How should be  system configured for use breakpoints of xdebug for phpunit(3.5) tests on netbeans 6.9 (ubuntu 10.04).

Example1 (breakpoint inside Test file): in  ExampleTest.php I want to put breakpoint in line 30, when test will run he will stop in line 30 and will able to see variables values etc..

Example2 (breakpoint inside source file): in  Example.php I want to put breakpoint in line 60, when test will run he will stop in line 30 and will able to see variables values etc..

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1):

Configure:

1. install firefox add-on easy xdebug :: http://www.elime.be/easyxdebug.htm
2. edit file /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini. My content:

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1

xdebug.remote_host=localhost

xdebug.remote_port=9000

3. [not required] in netbeans, edit project properties projects->youProject->Run Configuration->Advanced->Debug URL:Do Not Open Web Browser
4. [maybe not required] in netbeans - Tools->Options->PHP->General->Debugging->Debugger port 9000, Session ID: netbeans-xdebug

Run from Firefox:

1. Ctrl+f5 (Debug Project)

{if firefox}

2. in firefox, click on green bug with arrow in right bottom corner

{if cli}

2. add parameter netbeans-xdebug with value 1

{/if}

3. enjoy

Comment: thanks, but i am asking about phpunit tests that running from command line because that breakpoints not working